# How to call the correct overloaded method?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a class **A** with a subclass **B**. The class **A** has a method `foo()` that calls `C.test(this)`. In class **C**, there are two methods: `test(A a)` and `test(B b)`. Whenever `A.foo()` is called, the method `test(A a)` is used. That seems normal to me. However, whenever `B.foo()` is called, the method `test(A a)` is also used, instead of `test(B b)` (which is what I want). This surprises me.

Why does this happen? How can I change my code structure such that I obtain the behaviour that I want?

Comment: Please post a real-code example of exactly what you mean, a [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried overriding `foo()` in `B`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go off of an assumption that you're not overriding `A#foo` in `B`.  So when `A#foo` is called, `this` refers to `A` since the method runs in `A`.  To fix this, you can override the method in `B` by creating `B#foo` with the same implementation as its parent.  `this` will then refer to `B` instead of `A`, and the correct method in `C` will be called.